# How to identify the last edited registry key

Tags: winapi, registry

Windows registry is a valuable source of informations ,for purpose of audit and to isolate changes when the Operating system is being seen as a "finite state machine" and when changes are simple and "linear".

for instance,one can look for keys in the registry hives like "HKLM/system/currentcontrolset001"  after the installation of a new service ,or an update, to know whether the installed software is a critical service or not(so that deleting it will not result on system boot failure)..

.i'm looking for a reliable way to find  the last key that was edited by the user or even by the  system-not by an exterior utility but rather via an API function call or ,even, the registry itself...
i guess "regmon" is using such windows calls...

Comment: Look at SysInternals [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645).

Comment: Sounds like you will need to hook all registry write calls...